# How to return ECMASCRIPT 6 Promise from Breeze

Tags: breeze, q, es6-promise

A breeze query returns interface [breeze.Promises.IPromise](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/Promise.html).

It is using kris kowal's [Q promises.](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), and it uses a Q.Deferred to return a promise.

Q exposes a ES6 compliant Promise with Q.Promise.

How do I get a ES6 Promise out of a breeze query?  I basically am hoping for a slick way to convert a Q.Deferred to a Q.Promise.

```
function getES6Promise () {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Table");
    // How to return as an ES6 Promise?
    return em.executeQuery(query);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will have to configure breeze with a wrapper around the `Promise` that makes it look like a `Q`.

Breeze only needs a tiny part of the `Q` interface: `defer`, `resolve`, and `reject`. `defer` has a `promise` property. `resolve` and `reject` return promises. The promise can come from any library as long as it sports a suitable `then` method.

Here is a wrapper I cooked up off the top of my head but have not actually tried:

```
(function () {
  function defer() {
    var deferred = {}
    deferred.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      deferred.resolve = resolve;
      deferred.reject = reject;
    })
    return deferred;
  }
  var Q = {
    all: Promise.all,
    defer: defer,
    resolve: Promise.resolve,
    reject: Promise.reject
  }
  breeze.config.setQ(Q)
})()
```

FWIW, the  [breeze.Promises.IPromise](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/Promise.html) interface to which your refer is useless and should be removed from the documentation.

The fact of the matter is that the promise returned by a Breeze operation has the shape and characteristics of whatever promise library you choose and certainly need not adhere to *that* interface.

Many of the API and documentation examples use `fail` and `fin`. Obviously those are not methods of an ES6 promise and wouldn't work.  You'd want `catch` for `fail` and `then(finFn, finFn)` for `fin(finFn)`.

Fortunately, internally breeze calls `promise.then` exclusively and makes no use of these other promise methods.

Try my wrapper suggestion sometime and let us know how it works out.